# Tikz: Latex macros in draw to [in=,out=] and point coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to use latex macros in the calculation of the coordinates in a `\draw` command but that seems not to be possible if both the target point coordinates and `[in=...,out=...]` instructions involve such macros.

Take this MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\def\a{25}
\def\b{0}
\def\r{1.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- ({\r*cos(\b)},{\r*sin(\b)});
\draw [red] (0,0) to [out=\a,in=180-\a] (1.5,0);
\draw [blue] (0,0) to [out=-\a,in=180+\a] ({\r*cos(\b)},{\r*sin(\b)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first `\draw` command works fine, tikz does the sin and cos calculations; the second `\draw` command also works fine, latex substitutes `\a` before tikz processes the to `[in=-\a ,out=180+\a]` instruction. However, the final `\draw` command fails with error message

```
"""
! Package pgf Error: No shape named 1 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.11 ...-\a,in=180+\a] ({\r*cos(\b)},{\r*sin(\b)})  
"""
```

Why is this, and how can I get it to work?
Thanks
Jose

Answer (score 4):

The draw command `to` doesn't accept computed coordinates directly, you can simply create a named coordinate, or use proper polar coordinates as I do with the green line:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\a{25}
\newcommand*\b{0}
\newcommand*\r{1.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (target) at ({\r*cos(\b)},{\r*sin(\b)});
  \draw (0,0) -- (target);
  \draw [red] (0,0) to [out=\a,in=180-\a] (1.5,0);
  \draw [blue] (0,0) to [out=-\a,in=180+\a] (target);
  \draw [green,very thick,dashed] (0,0) to [out=-\a,in=180+\a] +(\b:\r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why your solution does not work, but this one works

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \begin{document}
    \def\a{25}
    \def\b{0}
    \def\r{1.5}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- ({\r*cos(\b)},{\r*sin(\b)});
    \draw [red] (0,0) to [out={\a},in={180-\a}] (1.5,0);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rC}{\r*cos(\b)}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\rS}{\r*sin(\b)}
  \draw [blue] (0,0) to [out={-\a},in={180+\a}] (\rC,\rS);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Ti*k*Z, which occurs whenever the x-coordinate after `to[in=...,out=...]` has a function, including `sin`, `cos`, `round`, `floor`, and so on.

A simple solution is to add another pair of curly brackets in the x-coordinate, like so:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\def\a{25}
\def\b{0}
\def\r{1.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- ({\r*cos(\b)},{\r*sin(\b)});
\draw [red] (0,0) to [out=\a,in=180-\a] (1.5,0);
\draw [blue] (0,0) to [out=-\a,in=180+\a] ({{\r*cos(\b)}},{\r*sin(\b)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```